# "Add" button dont working in Jenkins System settings

Tags: javascript, java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cicd

Please help colleagues. Jenkins 2.361.1.

Found a problem when clicking the "**Add**" button in **Manage Jenkins --> Configure system**. Nothing happens when pressed.

The Jenkins logs are empty, in the Browser console too.

Moreover, the buttons located in the **Global Pipeline Libraries** block do not work. I tried to update this plugin but it is already outdated, **Pipeline: Groovy Libraries** came in his place. Nothing has changed since installing it.
[GIF with a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyDlr.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the deprecated **Job Direct Mail Plugin** helped

Answer (score 0):

Hack - populate few values like 'name', 'url' etc. and then save it. Load the page. Now try adding the token again.